# Writing grammar rules for context sensitive elements using Pyparsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing, context-free-grammar, pyparsing

I am trying to write a grammar for a set of **sentences** and using [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) to parse it. These **sentences** tell what and how to search in a text file, and I need to convert them into corresponding regex search codes. However, there are some elements that are not really context-free and hence, I am finding it difficult to write production rules for them. Basically, my aim is to parse these sentences and then write regexes for them.

Some examples of context-sensitive elements found in these sentences -

1. `LINE_CONTAINS phrase1 BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3}` means in the line, `phrase1` can come anywhere before `phrase2` and `phrase`. Similarly for `AFTER`
2. `LINE_CONTAINS abc JOIN xyz` means search for `abc xyz` and `abc-xyz` and `abcxyz`
3. `LINE_CONTAINS abcd AND xyzw` means the line should contain both `abcd` and `xyzw`

---

Example - `LINE_CONTAINS we transfected BEFORE {sirna} AND gene AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore`

This should be converted to `re.search(r'(^!Therefore.*?we transfected.*?sirna)' and re.search(r'(gene))` (A better regex can be made I believe)

---

I had begun writing grammar for the sentences as -

```
Beginner = LINE_CONTAINS|LINE_STARTSWITH|other line beginners...
Phrase = word+
sentence = Beginner + phrase + AND + Beginner + phrase
```

Any of these motifs/elements can occur in any line and can be in combination too. Like

`LINE_CONTAINS {x AND y} BEFORE {a letter AND b letter} AND zoo people AND LINE_STARTSWITH dfg`

So my question is -

How do I write grammar rules that can handle such context-sensitive elements, given that any sentence can have them (though most sentences won't have multiple, but still). *Should I write rules for many kinds of sentences, each containing one of these different kinds of elements. Or should I write a rule that contains all such elements and make them optional.*

I do understand that these elements may not exactly be context-sensitive, but my problem lies in not being able to write independent production rules for elements like `BEFORE`, `JOIN` etc. How do I best define their function in the production rules?

**Edit -** The phrases can be multi-word

Comment: What is it about that grammar which makes it context-sensitive, in your opinion?

Comment: @rici the elements like `BEFORE`, `AND` etc. act according to the elements around it. that's what felt context-sensitive to me. But I would be willing to know if I am wrong

Comment: By that definition, aren't `+` and `*`  sensitive to their context in an ordinary algebraic expression? Or perhaps I'm not understanding the manner in which `BEFORE` reacts to its environment...Do you mean that in other contexts, it has a different meaning? Can you give an example so as to be more clear about your needs?

Comment: @rici I have provided an example and focussed my problem. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some guesses about your grammar, here is a rough stab. Notice how I separately define the line expressions from the phrase expressions:

```
from pyparsing import (CaselessKeyword, Word, alphas, MatchFirst, quotedString, 
    infixNotation, opAssoc, Suppress, Group)


LINE_CONTAINS, LINE_STARTSWITH, LINE_ENDSWITH = map(CaselessKeyword,
    """LINE_CONTAINS LINE_STARTSWITH LINE_ENDSWITH""".split())
NOT, AND, OR = map(CaselessKeyword, "NOT AND OR".split())
BEFORE, AFTER, JOIN = map(CaselessKeyword, "BEFORE AFTER JOIN".split())

keyword = MatchFirst([LINE_CONTAINS, LINE_STARTSWITH, LINE_ENDSWITH, NOT, AND, OR, 
                      BEFORE, AFTER, JOIN])
phrase_word = ~keyword + Word(alphas + '_')

phrase_term = phrase_word | quotedString

phrase_expr = infixNotation(phrase_term,
                            [
                             ((BEFORE | AFTER | JOIN), 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                             (NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT,),
                             (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                             (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                            ],
                            lpar=Suppress('{'), rpar=Suppress('}')
                            )

line_term = Group((LINE_CONTAINS | LINE_STARTSWITH | LINE_ENDSWITH)("line_directive") + 
                  Group(phrase_expr)("phrase"))
line_contents_expr = infixNotation(line_term,
                                   [(NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT,),
                                    (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                    ]
                                   )

sample = """
LINE_CONTAINS transfected BEFORE {sirna} AND gene AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore
"""

line_contents_expr.runTests(sample)
```

parses your sample as:

```
LINE_CONTAINS transfected BEFORE {sirna} AND gene AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore
[[['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna'], 'AND', 'gene']]], 'AND', ['LINE_STARTSWITH', ['Therefore']]]]
[0]:
  [['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna'], 'AND', 'gene']]], 'AND', ['LINE_STARTSWITH', ['Therefore']]]
  [0]:
    ['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna'], 'AND', 'gene']]]
    - line_directive: 'LINE_CONTAINS'
    - phrase: [[['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna'], 'AND', 'gene']]
      [0]:
        [['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna'], 'AND', 'gene']
        [0]:
          ['transfected', 'BEFORE', 'sirna']
        [1]:
          AND
        [2]:
          gene
  [1]:
    AND
  [2]:
    ['LINE_STARTSWITH', ['Therefore']]
    - line_directive: 'LINE_STARTSWITH'
    - phrase: ['Therefore']
```

The `phrase_word` starts with a negative lookahead, to avoid accidentally treating strings like 'LINE_STARTSWITH' as phrase words. I also added quoted strings as valid phrase words, since you never know when your search will have to actually include the string "LINE_STARTSWITH".

You use `{}`s for grouping in your phrase expressions, `infixNotation` has optional `lpar` and `rpar` arguments to override the defaults of `(` and `)`.

From here, you can look at other `infixNotation` examples (such as SimpleBool.py on the pyparsing wiki examples page) to convert this into your respective regex-generating code.

Comment: just taking my time to go through the code, since I am a newbie to Pyparsing. Will get back to you on this. Can't believe I am getting help from THE Paul McGuire!

Comment: to accommodate multi-word phrases, changed your code as - `phrase_term = OneOrMore(phrase_word) | quotedString`

Comment: Right, I was thinking about that. Wrap the OneOrMore in a Group to keep them all together and the structure more predictable

Comment: I also had another element, Paul. It is `{upto N words}` and is meant to be used as `abc {upto N words} xyz` which would tell me that I need to allow upto N(>1) words in between when searching for the term `abc xyz`. I had written its grammar as - `upto_N_words = lpar + 'upto' + numberofwords=Word(nums) + 'words' + rpar`. But the problem is to know the number N when parsing it. How can I do it? (also i cant assign `numberofwords` like that)

Comment: First, instead of `Word(nums)`, use pyparsing's new pyparsing_common namespace which contains many common expressions, such as `pyparsing_common.integer` which will also do the string->integer conversion. Attach the "numberofwords" results name using the `expr("name")` form: `upto_N_Words = Group(lpar + 'upto' + pyparsing_common.integer('numberofwords') + 'words' + rpar)` Now when this is parsed, you'll be able to use the 'numberofwords' results name, and the number will have already been converted to a Python int.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I had a couple more doubts. First, in my `phrase_term`, I need to allow multiple `{upto N words}` terms, so `phrase_term = Group(OneOrMore(phrase_word) + ZeroOrMore(upto_N_words) + OneOrMore(phrase_word))`, wouldn't work for cases like `LINE_CONTAINS we inhibited {upto 4 words} gene {upto 3 words} together`. So I was thinking if there was a way to allow words and motifs like `{upto..}` multiple times, say irrespective of order. Secondly, I wanted to access `numberofwords`, so I did `parsed=line_contents_expr.parseString(sample)` and `print parsed.numberofwords`, but it didnt work

Comment: one (bad) way to resolve the first problem would be `phrase_term = Group(OneOrMore(phrase_word) + ZeroOrMore((upto_N_words)+OneOrMore(phrase_word)))` but I also have `{upto N characters}` in the mix, which would disallow such a simplistic solution. So I was looking for a more general solution, which could allow some flexibility in the order (perhaps). Also, if you don't mind, I had a 3rd doubt. If my sentence has >1 `upto N words` (as in the example above), how do I access both `numberofwords`?

Comment: SO discourages long comment threads, and answering this goes beyond what I can enter in a comment. Open a new question specific to `{upto N words}` and `{upto N characters}`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to be a very simplistic grammar. I think you are "overthinking" the problem.

Looking at your examples, I see this:

```
a JOIN b
a BEFORE b

a AND b
a OR b

STARTSWITH a
```

Those are simply operators. Unary operators (STARTSWITH) are like `~x` or `-x` in python. Binary operators (JOIN, BEFORE, AND, OR) are like `x + y` or `x in y` in python.

I don't think `CONTAINS` is an operator, so much as a place-holder. Pretty much everything except `STARTSWITH` is implicitly a contains. So that's kind of like the unary-plus operator: defined, understood, allowed, but useless.

Anyway, figure out what the operators are (make a list). Figure out whether they are unary (startswith) or binary (and). Then figure out what their [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Examples) and [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Examples) are.

Once you know that information, you can build your parser: you will know the key words, and know how to arrange the key words in a grammar.

Comment: one problem for me is that since some sentences have multiple of these binary keywords, when I write production rules for them, do I mention all of these possibilities in the same rule (as optional). Basically the italicized part of my 'question'

Comment: I agree with Austin, these keywords look like operators, and could be arranged into an `infixNotation` expression (which would take care of things like repetition and `{}` grouping). You  will also probably need some negative lookahead in defining `phrase` so that LINE_CONTAINS, etc. do not get treated like phrase contents, but get recognized as keywords/operators.

Comment: A sentence having multiple occurrences of a keyword (operator) is no different than an arithmetic expression having multiple occurrences of an operator. Like `a + b + 2 * c`. If you identify the operators, their precedence, and their associativity, then you can parse them just like any other expression.

If you say "Line contains 'a' before 'b' before 'c'" it should be straightforward to convert that into `((a < b) < c)` in your parsing.