# Access parsed elements using Pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have a bunch of sentences which I need to parse and convert to corresponding regex search code. Examples of my sentences -

`LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore we`

-This means in the line, `phrase one` comes somewhere before
`phrase2` and `phrase3`. Also, the line must start with `Therefore we`

`LINE_CONTAINS abc {upto 4 words} xyz {upto 3 words} pqr`

-This means I need to allow upto 4 words between the first 2 phrases and 
upto 3 words between last 2 phrases

Using help from Paul Mcguire ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42415837/4169943)), the following grammar was written -

```
from pyparsing import (CaselessKeyword, Word, alphanums, nums, MatchFirst, quotedString, 
    infixNotation, Combine, opAssoc, Suppress, pyparsing_common, Group, OneOrMore, ZeroOrMore)

LINE_CONTAINS, LINE_STARTSWITH = map(CaselessKeyword,
    """LINE_CONTAINS LINE_STARTSWITH """.split()) 

NOT, AND, OR = map(CaselessKeyword, "NOT AND OR".split())
BEFORE, AFTER, JOIN = map(CaselessKeyword, "BEFORE AFTER JOIN".split())

lpar=Suppress('{') 
rpar=Suppress('}')

keyword = MatchFirst([LINE_CONTAINS, LINE_STARTSWITH, LINE_ENDSWITH, NOT, AND, OR, 
                      BEFORE, AFTER, JOIN]) # declaring all keywords and assigning order for all further use

phrase_word = ~keyword + (Word(alphanums + '_'))

upto_N_words = Group(lpar + 'upto' + pyparsing_common.integer('numberofwords') + 'words' + rpar)

phrase_term = Group(OneOrMore(phrase_word) + ZeroOrMore((upto_N_words) + OneOrMore(phrase_word))  



phrase_expr = infixNotation(phrase_term,
                            [
                             ((BEFORE | AFTER | JOIN), 2, opAssoc.LEFT,), # (opExpr, numTerms, rightLeftAssoc, parseAction)
                             (NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT,),
                             (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                             (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                            ],
                            lpar=Suppress('{'), rpar=Suppress('}')
                            ) # structure of a single phrase with its operators

line_term = Group((LINE_CONTAINS | LINE_STARTSWITH | LINE_ENDSWITH)("line_directive") + 
                  Group(phrase_expr)("phrase")) # basically giving structure to a single sub-rule having line-term and phrase
line_contents_expr = infixNotation(line_term,
                                   [(NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT,),
                                    (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                    ]
                                   ) # grammar for the entire rule/sentence

sample1 = """
LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore we
"""
sample2 = """
LINE_CONTAINS abcd {upto 4 words} xyzw {upto 3 words} pqrs BEFORE something else
"""
```

---

My question now is - How do I access the parsed elements in order to convert the sentences to my regex code. For this, I tried the following -

```
parsed = line_contents_expr.parseString(sample1)/(sample2)
print (parsed[0].asDict())
print (parsed)
pprint.pprint(parsed)
```

The result of the above code for `sample1` was -

> {}
>
> [[['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['sentence', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['sentence2'],
>   'AND', ['sentence3']]]]], 'AND', ['LINE_STARTSWITH', [['Therefore',
>   'we']]]]]
>
> ([([(['LINE_CONTAINS', ([([(['sentence', 'one'], {}), 'BEFORE',
>   ([(['sentence2'], {}), 'AND', (['sentence3'], {})], {})], {})], {})],
>   {'**phrase**': [(([([(['sentence', 'one'], {}), 'BEFORE',
>   ([(['sentence2'], {}), 'AND', (['sentence3'], {})], {})], {})], {}),
>   1)], '**line_directive**': [('LINE_CONTAINS', 0)]}), 'AND',
>   (['LINE_STARTSWITH', ([(['Therefore', 'we'], {})], {})], {'**phrase**':
>   [(([(['Therefore', 'we'], {})], {}), 1)], '**line_directive**':
>   [('LINE_STARTSWITH', 0)]})], {})], {})

The result of the above code for `sample2` was -

> {'**phrase**': [[['abcd', {'**numberofwords**': 4}, 'xyzw', {'**numberofwords**':
>   3}, 'pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]], '**line_directive**':
>   'LINE_CONTAINS'}
>
> [['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['abcd', ['upto', 4, 'words'], 'xyzw', ['upto',
>   3, 'words'], 'pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]]]]
>
> ([(['LINE_CONTAINS', ([([(['abcd', (['upto', 4, 'words'],
>   {'**numberofwords**': [(4, 1)]}), 'xyzw', (['upto', 3, 'words'],
>   {'**numberofwords**': [(3, 1)]}), 'pqrs'], {}), 'BEFORE', (['something',
>   'else'], {})], {})], {})], {'phrase': [(([([(['abcd', (['upto', 4,
>   'words'], {'**numberofwords**': [(4, 1)]}), 'xyzw', (['upto', 3, 'words'],
>   {'numberofwords': [(3, 1)]}), 'pqrs'], {}), 'BEFORE', (['something',
>   'else'], {})], {})], {}), 1)], '**line_directive**': [('LINE_CONTAINS',
>   0)]})], {})

My questions based on the above output are -

1. Why does the pprint (pretty print) have more detailed parsing than normal print?
2. Why does the `asDict()` method give no output for `sample1` but does for `sample2`?
3. Whenever I try to access the parsed elements using `print (parsed.numberofwords)` or `parsed.line_directive` or `parsed.line_term`, it gives me nothing. How can I access these elements in order to use them to build my regex codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your printing questions. 1) `pprint` is there to pretty print a nested list of tokens, without showing any results names - it is essentially a wraparound for calling `pprint.pprint(results.asList())`.  2) `asDict()` is there to do conversion of your parsed results to an actual Python dict, so it *only* shows the results names (with nesting if you have names within names).

To view the contents of your parsed output, you are best off using `print(result.dump())`.  `dump()` shows both the nesting of the results *and* any named results along the way.

```
result = line_contents_expr.parseString(sample2)
print(result.dump())
```

I also recommend using `expr.runTests` to give you `dump()` output as well as any exceptions and exception locators. With your code, you could most easily do this using:

```
line_contents_expr.runTests([sample1, sample2])
```

But I also suggest you step back a second and think about just what this `{upto n words}` business is all about. Look at your samples and draw rectangles around the line terms, and then within the line terms draw circles around the phrase terms. (This would be a good exercise in leading up to writing for yourself a BNF description of this grammar, which I always recommend as a getting-your-head-around-the-problem step.) What if you treated the `upto` expressions as another operator? To see this, change `phrase_term` back to the way you had it:

```
phrase_term = Group(OneOrMore(phrase_word))
```

And then change your first precedence entry in defining a phrase expression to:

```
    ((BEFORE | AFTER | JOIN | upto_N_words), 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
```

Or give some thought to maybe having `upto` operator at a higher or lower precedence than BEFORE, AFTER, and JOIN, and adjust the precedence list accordingly.

With this change, I get this output from calling runTests on your samples:

```
LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH Therefore we

[[['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['phrase', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]]]], 'AND', ['LINE_STARTSWITH', [['Therefore', 'we']]]]]
[0]:
  [['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['phrase', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]]]], 'AND', ['LINE_STARTSWITH', [['Therefore', 'we']]]]
  [0]:
    ['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['phrase', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]]]]
    - line_directive: 'LINE_CONTAINS'
    - phrase: [[['phrase', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]]]
      [0]:
        [['phrase', 'one'], 'BEFORE', [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]]
        [0]:
          ['phrase', 'one']
        [1]:
          BEFORE
        [2]:
          [['phrase2'], 'AND', ['phrase3']]
          [0]:
            ['phrase2']
          [1]:
            AND
          [2]:
            ['phrase3']
  [1]:
    AND
  [2]:
    ['LINE_STARTSWITH', [['Therefore', 'we']]]
    - line_directive: 'LINE_STARTSWITH'
    - phrase: [['Therefore', 'we']]
      [0]:
        ['Therefore', 'we']



LINE_CONTAINS abcd {upto 4 words} xyzw {upto 3 words} pqrs BEFORE something else

[['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['abcd'], ['upto', 4, 'words'], ['xyzw'], ['upto', 3, 'words'], ['pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]]]]
[0]:
  ['LINE_CONTAINS', [[['abcd'], ['upto', 4, 'words'], ['xyzw'], ['upto', 3, 'words'], ['pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]]]
  - line_directive: 'LINE_CONTAINS'
  - phrase: [[['abcd'], ['upto', 4, 'words'], ['xyzw'], ['upto', 3, 'words'], ['pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]]
    [0]:
      [['abcd'], ['upto', 4, 'words'], ['xyzw'], ['upto', 3, 'words'], ['pqrs'], 'BEFORE', ['something', 'else']]
      [0]:
        ['abcd']
      [1]:
        ['upto', 4, 'words']
        - numberofwords: 4
      [2]:
        ['xyzw']
      [3]:
        ['upto', 3, 'words']
        - numberofwords: 3
      [4]:
        ['pqrs']
      [5]:
        BEFORE
      [6]:
        ['something', 'else']
```

You can iterate over these results and pick them apart, but you are rapidly reaching the point where you should look at building executable nodes from the different precedence levels - see the SimpleBool.py example on the pyparsing wiki for how to do this.

EDIT: Please review this pared-down version of a parser for `phrase_expr`, and how it creates `Node` instances that themselves generate the output. See how `numberofwords` is accessed on the operator in the `UpToNode` class. See how "xyz abc" gets interpreted as "xyz AND abc" with an implicit AND operator.

```
from pyparsing import *
import re

UPTO, WORDS, AND, OR = map(CaselessKeyword, "upto words and or".split())
keyword = UPTO | WORDS | AND | OR
LBRACE,RBRACE = map(Suppress, "{}")
integer = pyparsing_common.integer()

word = ~keyword + Word(alphas)
upto_expr = Group(LBRACE + UPTO + integer("numberofwords") + WORDS + RBRACE)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def generate(self):
        pass

class LiteralNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        return "(%s)" % re.escape(self.tokens[0])
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.tokens[0])

class AndNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        return '.*'.join(t.generate() for t in tokens[::2])

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' AND '.join(repr(t) for t in self.tokens[0].asList()[::2])

class OrNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        return '|'.join(t.generate() for t in tokens[::2])

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' OR '.join(repr(t) for t in self.tokens[0].asList()[::2])

class UpToNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        ret = tokens[0].generate()
        word_re = r"\s+\S+"
        space_re = r"\s+"
        for op, operand in zip(tokens[1::2], tokens[2::2]):
            # op contains the parsed "upto" expression
            ret += "((%s){0,%d}%s)" % (word_re, op.numberofwords, space_re) + operand.generate()
        return ret

    def __repr__(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        ret = repr(tokens[0])
        for op, operand in zip(tokens[1::2], tokens[2::2]):
            # op contains the parsed "upto" expression
            ret += " {0-%d WORDS} " % (op.numberofwords) + repr(operand)
        return ret

IMPLICIT_AND = Empty().setParseAction(replaceWith("AND"))

phrase_expr = infixNotation(word.setParseAction(LiteralNode),
        [
        (upto_expr, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, UpToNode),
        (AND | IMPLICIT_AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, AndNode),
        (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, OrNode),
        ])

tests = """\
        xyz
        xyz abc
        xyz {upto 4 words} def""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    t = t.strip()
    if not t:
        continue
    print(t)
    try:
        parsed = phrase_expr.parseString(t)
    except ParseException as pe:
        print(' '*pe.loc + '^')
        print(pe)
        continue
    print(parsed)
    print(parsed[0].generate())
    print()
```

prints:

```
xyz
['xyz']
(xyz)

xyz abc
['xyz' AND 'abc']
(xyz).*(abc)

xyz {upto 4 words} def
['xyz' {0-4 WORDS} 'def']
(xyz)((\s+\S+){0,4}\s+)(def)
```

Expand on this to support your `LINE_xxx` expressions.

Comment: Paul, do you suggest that I manipulate from the contents of the `results.dump()` string in order to process the elements for further work?

Comment: No, no, absolutely not! I'm simply directing you to `results.dump()` as a way to visualize the contents of `results`. You should be able to iterate over the `results` directly when iterating a list, and reference fields by name using dict or object syntax. The `dump()` output should guide you as to which mode to use and when.

Comment: Paul, you mention how I can easily visualize the parse results using `dump` and `runTests`. But as I mention in the question, I was trying to access the elements of the parse to manipulate them into regexes. My question 3 specifically. How do you suggest I access things like both `numberofwords`, `line_term` etc. for the parsed line?

Comment: The examples you have now are a little complex to start this next step. Step back, start small, and start thinking about wrapping your regex generating code in objects. Parse a simple phrase expression like "xyz", then do "xyz abc", then do "{upto 3 words}".  Parse these and use the results to create a PhraseExpressionProcessor class instance, and add a generate() method to this class that will generate the appropriate regex. The point is that you will process these expressions in small pieces, and then merge the pieces.

Comment: Paul, the `IMPLICIT_AND` is really not appropriate. A sentence like `xyz abc` is to be matched exactly as `xyz abc`. Gaps between words only occur when specified (like using `upto..` or `BEFORE`). I tried to remove it, but then it just parsed the first word

Comment: Then go back to doing `Group(OneOrMore(word))` as you had before.  But I thought I saw in one of your earlier posts that two consecutive words indicated that you wanted them in that order, but with potential intervening words.

Comment: Yes, I do need exact matching. However on doing `Group` at `word=`, it gives the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'` at the line `return "(%s)" % re.escape(self.tokens[0])` (in the `LiteralNode` generate function). But I will try to figure it