# Preferential parsing of sentence elements using infixnotation in Pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have some sentences that I need to convert to regex code and I was trying to use Pyparsing for it. The sentences are basically search rules, telling us what to search for.

Examples of sentences -

1. `LINE_CONTAINS this is a phrase`
   -this is an example search rule telling that the line you are searching on should have the phrase `this is a phrase`
2. `LINE_STARTSWITH However we` - this is an example search rule telling that the line you are searching on should start with the phrase `However we`
3. The rules can be combined too, like- `LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH However we`

Now, I am trying to parse these sentences and then convert them to regex code. All lines start with either of the 2 symbols mentioned above (call them line_directives). I want to be able to consider these line_directives, and parse them appropriately and do the same for the phrase that follow them, albeit differently parsed. Using help from Paul McGuire([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629293/access-parsed-elements-using-pyparsing))and my own inputs, I have the following code-

```
from pyparsing import *
import re

UPTO, AND, OR, WORDS = map(Literal, "upto AND OR words".split())
keyword = UPTO | WORDS | AND | OR
LBRACE,RBRACE = map(Suppress, "{}")
integer = pyparsing_common.integer()

LINE_CONTAINS, LINE_STARTSWITH, LINE_ENDSWITH = map(Literal,
    """LINE_CONTAINS LINE_STARTSWITH LINE_ENDSWITH""".split()) # put option for LINE_ENDSWITH. Users may use, I don't presently
BEFORE, AFTER, JOIN = map(Literal, "BEFORE AFTER JOIN".split())
word = ~keyword + Word(alphas)
phrase = Group(OneOrMore(word))
upto_expr = Group(LBRACE + UPTO + integer("numberofwords") + WORDS + RBRACE)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def generate(self):
        pass

class LiteralNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        print (self.tokens[0], 20)
        for el in self.tokens[0]:
            print (el,type(el), 19)
        print (type(self.tokens[0]), 18)
        return "(%s)" %(' '.join(self.tokens[0])) # here, merged the elements, so that re.escape does not have to do an escape for the entire list
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.tokens[0])

class AndNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        return '.*'.join(t.generate() for t in tokens[::2]) # change this to the correct form of AND in regex

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' AND '.join(repr(t) for t in self.tokens[0].asList()[::2])


class OrNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        return '|'.join(t.generate() for t in tokens[::2])
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' OR '.join(repr(t) for t in self.tokens[0].asList()[::2])


class UpToNode(Node):
    def generate(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        ret = tokens[0].generate()
        print (123123)
        word_re = r"\s+\S+"
        space_re = r"\s+"
        for op, operand in zip(tokens[1::2], tokens[2::2]):
            # op contains the parsed "upto" expression
            ret += "((%s){0,%d}%s)" % (word_re, op.numberofwords, space_re) + operand.generate()
        print ret
        return ret


    def __repr__(self):
        tokens = self.tokens[0]
        ret = repr(tokens[0])
        for op, operand in zip(tokens[1::2], tokens[2::2]):
            # op contains the parsed "upto" expression
            ret += " {0-%d WORDS} " % (op.numberofwords) + repr(operand)
        return ret

phrase_expr = infixNotation(phrase,
                            [
                             ((BEFORE | AFTER | JOIN), 2, opAssoc.LEFT,), # (opExpr, numTerms, rightLeftAssoc, parseAction)
                             (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                             (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                            ],
                            lpar=Suppress('{'), rpar=Suppress('}')
                            ) # structure of a single phrase with its operators
line_term = Group((LINE_CONTAINS | LINE_STARTSWITH | LINE_ENDSWITH)("line_directive") + 
                  Group(phrase_expr)("phrase")) # basically giving structure to a single sub-rule having line-term and phrase
line_contents_expr = infixNotation(line_term,
                                   [(AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                    ]
                                   ) # grammar for the entire rule/sentence

phrase_expr = infixNotation(line_contents_expr.setParseAction(LiteralNode),
        [
        (upto_expr, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, UpToNode),
        (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, AndNode),
        (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, OrNode),
        ])

tests1 = """LINE_CONTAINS overexpressing gene AND other things""".splitlines()        
for t in tests1:
    t = t.strip()
    if not t:
        continue
#    print(t, 12)
    try:
        parsed = phrase_expr.parseString(t)
    except ParseException as pe:
        print(' '*pe.loc + '^')
        print(pe)
        continue
print (parsed[0], 14)
print (type(parsed[0]))
print(parsed[0].generate(), 15)
```

This simple code, on running gives the following error-

> ((['LINE_CONTAINS', ([(['overexpressing', 'gene'], {})], {})],
>   {'phrase': [(([(['overexpressing', 'gene'], {})], {}), 1)],
>   'line_directive': [('LINE_CONTAINS', 0)]}), 14)
>
> ((['LINE_CONTAINS', ([(['overexpressing', 'gene'], {})], {})],
>   {'phrase': [(([(['overexpressing', 'gene'], {})], {}), 1)],
>   'line_directive': [('LINE_CONTAINS', 0)]}), 20)
>
> ('LINE_CONTAINS', <, 19)
>
> (([(['overexpressing', 'gene'], {})], {}), , 19)
>
> (, 18)
>
> TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, ParseResults found (line
>   29)

(The error code is not completely correct, as angular brackets are not well supported in blockquote here)

So my question is, even though I have written the grammar (using `infixnotation`) such that it treats `LINE_CONTAINS` as a line_directive and parse the remaining the line accordingly, why is it not able to parse properly? What is a good way to parse such lines?

Comment: I think you need `phrase` to be converted from a ParseResults to a string - try `phrase = Group(OneOrMore(word)).setParseAction(' '.join)`  I think you had it this way before.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, i did that now, but it gives the TypeError-`TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`. I will also try to look into it

Comment: What version of pyparsing are you running?

Comment: the pyparsing.py file mentions 'version 2.1.4'

Comment: Must be `phrase = Group(OneOrMore(word)).setParseAction(' '.join)`, not `phrase = Group(OneOrMore(word)).setParseAction(' '.join())`.

Comment: yup Paul, that's what i entered, but the error is still 
  `File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 819, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])

TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138977/discussion-between-paul-mcguire-and-user1993).

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, could you have a look at the related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233734/how-to-write-grammar-for-an-expression-when-it-can-have-many-possible-forms) where I try to write a systematic BNF?